# Setting custom Google Storage Bucket wide max-age header

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cache-control, max-age, google-bucket

Respected Seniors,
I am using google storage bucket to store the static content of my website. I wanted this content to be cached in CDN, that is why I have made the bucket public, which results in setting https headers Cache-control to public and max-age to 3600 by default.
I want to set max-age to higher value for all the future objects those will be uploaded in bucket.
I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution online.
Please guide me if there is any way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata), the headers returned when accessing an object can be set modifying the metadata associated to it. There are two categories of metadata, one that's fixed and the other that is custom. The metadata/header Cache-Control is one of the fixed-key metadatas.

In the section about [Cache-Control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control) it is said that we can modify said header in order to modify the cache settings. If not provided, the value is set to `public, max-age=3600`.

Using one public bucket of mine I have edited the Cache-Control to have the value `public, max-age=5000` and when requesting the object the header was set with the correct value. Take a look at [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit) in order to know how you can modify the metadata.

---

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612857/10810527), in order to automatically set the right header in the future objects of a bucket, a Cloud Function that uses the [storage trigger finalize](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize) could be used so that it runs whenever an object gets uploaded/overwritten and changes the object's metadata.

```py
from google.cloud import storage

CACHE_CONTROL = "public, max-age=3159200"

def set_cache_control_private(data, context):
    print('Setting Cache-Control to {} for: gs://{}/{}'.format(CACHE_CONTROL, data['bucket'], data['name']))
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(data['bucket'])
    blob = bucket.get_blob(data['name'])
    blob.cache_control = CACHE_CONTROL
    blob.patch()
```

Notice how the code itself is almost the same as the other answer, but setting the Cache-Control to the new value that we decided.

Also the `requirements.txt` file is needed with this content:

```
google-cloud-storage
```

Comment: I know this vale can be set using cloud console for each object.
What I am looking is a way to modify it for each new/modified object automatically. There is a way of doing it, explained in this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812857/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-whole-google-storage-bucket-have-preset-metadata].
Since I am new to coding stuff, so couldn't follow it properly and my I couldn't post a comment on the post asking for explanation because of limited reputation points.
it would be nice of you, If you could guide or get an explanation on my behalf.

Comment: same is explained here as well [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147546/set-google-storage-buckets-default-cache-control/51612857#51612857]
what changes should I make in it to set cache-control to public, max-age=3159200???

Comment: I have updated my answer explaining the code that should be used in a CF in order to update new objects. Take a look and add a comment if you feel like it doesn't still solve your issue.

Comment: thank you so much for your guidance.it solved my problem

Comment: @Shamsulhassan If an answer in a SO question you posted solves your issue, it is expected that you accept it so it's found more easily by people who are facing the same issue as you did. If this answer solves your issue, accept it. If it still needs improvement do not hesitate to edit it and improve it before doing so.